# Is there an image name convention for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using an image that will fill the full view of an iPhone. For iPhone 3GS we name it image.png for iPhone 4 we name it image@2x.png -is there an image name convention for iPhone 5 where it will automatically substitute it, or do I need to manually check which device I'm on?

I've read elsewhere that we keep on using @2x but I don't want my image stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific image name conventions for iPhone 5 except for the Default-568h@2x.png image.

Your images will not be stretched when you use @2x on the iPhone 5, it is just the layout that will change.

Comment: I'm using this image as a view background.  Using @2x produces a gap at the bottom of the view (which it would at it's 176px too short).  So I do need to use an iPhone 5 specific image.  I'll just check the view height and replace the image.

Comment: You can use `[UIDevice currentDevice]` to know which device your app is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no specific naming convention for the 4" screen (5th gen iPod touch and iPhone 5), you need to check the screen height yourself and load a different image.

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {
    // 4" screen - load appropriate image
} else {
    // regular screen - load standard image
}
```

This will work in portrait orientation.